# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't accept class com.veersoft.gwt.shared.trailbalance.TrailBalanceClassResult as a memcache entity

Tags: google-app-engine, memcached, objectify

Inorder to make my application faster, I'm using the `MemcacheService`. Now, while I'm trying to put an object into the `MemcacheService`, I'm getting the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't accept class com.veersoft.gwt.shared.trailbalance.TrailBalanceClassResult as a memcache entity.
```

Details about the entity:

1. It's a normal Bean which implements IsSerializable interface.
2. It is not a dataStore entity. I'm using this just to render at the browser side(i.e., the deferred task will calculate the results and will send these results to the browser).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To put any object in memcache, it needs to implement the `Serializable` interface. `IsSerializable` is an anachronism from an old version of GWT and does not affect java serialization in any way.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestion. EveryThing went fine.